# python pandas dataframe applying multiple html styles at the same time

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

rows=3
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'dtime': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=rows, freq='15T'), 
     'Customer' : np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=rows),
     'Amount': [random.randint(1, 1000000) for x in range(3)]
    })
df
```

[image]

I would like to export the dataframe to html but column Amount should be with thousands ("," not ".") separator and right aligned. This html should be with no css styles because I will send it as body in html email message.

If I execute `df.to_html()`
I get:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>dtime</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>2020-01-01 00:00:00</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>302422</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2020-01-01 00:15:00</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>9933</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>2020-01-01 00:30:00</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>843669</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

which is close, but I need right align and thousands separator.
In order to do so, I tried

`df.to_html(formatters = {'Amount': lambda x: f'{x:,}'})`

which produced kind of improvement:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>dtime</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>2020-01-01 00:00:00</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>302,422</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2020-01-01 00:15:00</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>9,933</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>2020-01-01 00:30:00</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>843,669</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

I still need right align which I cannot get with `df.to_html()`.
As I can see both requirements can be done with

```
df.style.format({'Amount':'{:,}'}).set_properties(subset='Amount', **{'text-align': 'right'}).render()
```

But in that case, I don't have table border.

[image]

How to get border and for column Amount thousands separator and right align at the same time, by using only html tags?

I need a way to put `border="1" class="dataframe"` in the `<table>` tag.